# counting odd and even digts in a given number using C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I count the even and the odd integers in a given number in C++?
For example: The user inputs: 32478
             output: 3 even numbers and 2 odd numbers.

Comment: SO is not meant to do your homework for you.  Write some code and then come here when (if) you encounter a specific problem.  As it stands, your "question" is nothing more than a plea for someone to do the assignment for you.

Comment: Agreed, @iCodez .. though your username makes my eye twitch ;)

Comment: @Moo-Juice - Says the man named "Moo-Juice". Is that supposed to be milk? :P

Comment: @iCodez, fair point.. .and yes :D

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about this is a homework request.

Answer (score 6):

The basic algorithm is:

1. Take the number modulo 2 (`num % 2`). If the result is 1 then the number is odd; increment the odd counter. If not then it's even; increment the even counter.
2. Divide the number by 10, dropping the remainder. (`num /= 10`)
3. Go back to step 1 if the number isn't zero.

Comment: Just a related question. Internally, conversion from float to int do a `floor` or `round`? I tested and looks like it works like floor.. but I was wondering if it is a defined behavior.

Comment: @wendelbsilva Neither, it yields the same result as `trunc()`. Conversion to an integer type from a floating-point type will simply truncate the non-integer component. This is not the same thing as `floor()`: with -1.5, `floor()` returns -2 while truncation yields -1.

Comment: Wonderful Answer to a terrible question. Good job.